# Node JS - executing a string of code in a new process

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, sandbox

Let's say I have a string of NodeJS code I want to execute, but it's untrusted, and thus I must sandbox it, using `vm.runInNewContext(stringOfCode)`. Two questions arise:

1. If I do have some objects I want to use within the executed code, how may that bee achieved?
2. Let's say I want to limit the execution time of the code to 5 seconds, how may I do that?
3. How may I run this code on a new process? I now I can use `child_process.fork()`, but how exactly will I do that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `sandbox` argument you provide to `vm.runInNewContext()` is the object which will be available to the sandboxed code. Put there anything you need to use from inside. It's described in the docs:

http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename

2. But as the documentation says, you should better put the untrusted code into a separate process. Otherwise the code could simply hang with `while(true);`. As you mentioned yourself, the `chlid_process.fork()` shoudl be used for that. The docs are here:

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

But in this case you cannot transfer the objects to the new process, the messaging should be used instead.

Finally there's a library which simplifies everything above:

https://github.com/asvd/jailed